# How to detect if text replacement results in an infinite loop?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I develop a program that extracts text from other programs. One of the features is that users can specify "replacement scripts" to process the text. Example replacement script:

```
|ORIG|a|BECOMES|bb|END|
|ORIG|b|BECOMES|cc|END|
```

The replacement process searches for any `ORIG` text and replaces it with the corresponding `BECOMES` text. So if the text `aaaa` was extracted, it would be replaced first to `bbbbbbbb` and then to `cccccccccccccccc`.

The problem arises when there is a replacement script like this:

```
|ORIG|a|BECOMES|bb|END|
|ORIG|b|BECOMES|aa|END|
```

and there is an `a` in the extracted text. That `a` becomes `bb` which becomes `aaaa` which becomes `bbbbbbbb` and so on for infinity.

Thus I need two algorithms:
1. Read a replacement script and detect if it could possibly create an infinite loop (so I can warn the user).
2. Detect a infinite loop when executing a replacement script (so I can abort the operation and notify the user).

I have no idea where to start. I've thought about this for over two weeks and have gotten nowhere.

Comment: I am no computer scientist, but I have a feeling this is not possible. Detecting a loop while running would only be possible if you can store every version of the output while running, requiring infinite storage. Detecting a potential loop by analysing the script just doesn't seem possible to me. You can detect negatives, but not all positives, I think. It's reminiscent of the halting problem.

Comment: why do you need to run the rules all the time? I would think its more natural for the user to run the replacement rules just once in the order they were defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, my replacement scripts are actually Turing complete. Thus the question reduces to the halting problem and is unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build a graph with the nodes representing your replacement scripts and edges connecting one script with another if the ORIG of the first script is part of the BECOMES of the second script.

Then you could search for loops in this graph, telling you that your can indefinitely apply the rules in this loop.

Comment: That fails on a script like this: `|ORIG|a|BECOMES|b|END||ORIG|c|BECOMES|b|END||ORIG|bb|BECOMES|acac|END|` since no `BECOMES` has `bb` in it.

Comment: With your replacement scripts you effectively can model a type-0 grammar for which you had to decide if the generated language is finite (i.e. you can only do so many steps to reach every possible replacement result), which is, as far as i know, not decideable.

Answer (score 0):

If any ORIG is equal to or a substring of any BECOMES then you could have issues.

Comment: But the first replacement script in the question has that, and it clearly can't loop infinitely. I guess I could throw a lot of false positive warnings, but I'd really like to do better.